# Counting non-decreasing sequence of fixed length with restrictions on the repeated entries

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the following problem: Let $f(d,n)$ denote the number of non-decreasing sequences of length $d$ with entries from $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Here, 1 and $n$ can be repeated, but every other entry should appear at most once. By enumeration, I worked out several special cases. For instance, $f(d,2) = d + 1$ (using the stars and bars method) and
$ f(d,4) = 4d$
for $d = 1,2,3,4,5$. I wonder what a general formula for $f(d,n)$ might be. I want to use the stars and bars method, but I'm having difficulty figuring out the exact counting method.

Comment: Not sure the repetition bit means much...if you had a non-decreasing word on $\{2, \cdots, n-1\}$ with no repetition, you could preface it with $1^a$ and precede it with $n^b$, so you are really just down to counting the non-decreasing words on $\{2, \cdots, n-1\}$ with no repetition.  Which is just the subsets of that set.

Comment: @lulu In this case, the entries 2 and 3 cannot be repeated. So the set would be {11,12,13,14,23,24,34,44}. Thank you for your earlier remark!

Comment: Oh, of course.  My error.  I'll delete that incorrect comment.  the first comment should be correct, however.

Comment: @lulu I think the answer would then be $\sum_{l=0}^{d}(d - l + 1)\binom{n-2}{l}$. I will try to derive a closed-form formula now. Following your ideal, $l$ is the length of the word on ${2,\dots,n-1}$.